# How can I make frama-c exit non-zero on alarm or error?

Tags: frama-c

In the event that Frama-C has an alarm or an error, it still exits `0`, which makes it tricky to incorporate Frama-C into CI or other automation tooling.

Is there a way to get Frama-C to exit non-zero in the event of errors or alarms?

Comment: This issue on Frama-C may help you: https://git.frama-c.com/pub/frama-c/-/issues/54

Comment: @Ksass'Peuk Thanks!